# Import KeePass database with key file to Pass

Tags: password, keepassx

I have a KeePass database that is protected with a password and a key file and I'm trying to import it into Pass with a script. Unfortunately, the key file is giving me trouble.
As far as I know, pass-import doesn't support key files, does it? So I tried duplicating by database, removing the key file in the copy, import the copy to Pass and delete the copy afterwards. However, I wasn't able to find out how to remove a key file from a database using the command line. I know that you can change a key file with KPScript using the -newkeyfile option but what am I supposed to put there. I tried leaving it blank (-newkeyfile: and -newkeyfile:"") but that didn't work.

Does anybody have an idea, how to remove the key file from within the command line or know of some other way that lets me import my database to Pass.

I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Thanks for this question, because it led me to a solution. I successfully used a keepass GUI client to remove my key file, and then pass-import worked perfectly. The client I used was KeeWeb. See https://github.com/roddhjav/pass-import/issues/101